# Dynamically nested forms with has_many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, has-many-through

My project is a website for a championship and as such it's got `Calendar` that has and belongs to many `Disciplines` and what I'd like to do is upon creation of Calendar, be able to add many disciplines through checkboxes, but also - upon selecting the checkbox, I'd like to be able to use a `<select>` dropdown to state for which age group the given discipline belongs to.

So the code looks like this:

```
<% Discipline.all.each do |discipline| %>
    <%= check_box_tag "calendar[discipline_ids][]", discipline.id, @calendar.discipline_ids.include(discipline.id?) %>
    <%= discipline.title %>
<% end %>
```

**Calendar model**

```
has_many :calendar_disciplines
has_many :disciplines, through: :calendar_disciplines
```

**Discipine model**

```
has_many :calendar_disciplines
has_many :calendars, through: :calendar_disciplines
```

and so yeah - I'd like to add another input field (a select dropdown) next to the checkbox so that the user could choose if the discipline is for adults, U-15 or both and if it's for men, women or both.

Can you please show me how it's done?

Thank you.

Comment: I guess you want the contents of the second checkbox to depend on the selection of the first one. I have not seen this done without some piece of JavaScript which is triggered from the first checkbox. This may either retrieve the contents of the second box from the server or all options have already been cached and the script will just have to select the right one. Basically this goes beyond the capabilities of ordinary HTML.

Comment: What @Patru said. But you will also need accepts_nested_attributes_for :disciplines in your calendars model to be able to modify anything. You'll also have to white list the specific attributes on your calendars controller.

Comment: A fairly simple piece of JavaScript code which just enables and disables secondary select boxes based on the first one can be found in the [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/wT3Jk/1/) of the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7085622/cascading-combo-box-html).